# What Is Bigger $\frac{3}{e}$ or $\ln(3)$

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Hello everyone what is bigger $\frac{3}{e}$ or  $\ln(3)$?

I tried to square it at $e$ up and I got:

$e^{\frac{3}{e}} = \left(e^{e^{-1}}\right)^{3\:}$ and $3$ but I don't know how to continue I also tried to convert it to a function but I didn't find.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to determining whether $\ln 3 - \ln (\ln 3)$ or $1$ is greater. If you let $f(x) = \ln x - \ln (\ln x)$, then you can find the minimum using calculus and find the number which is larger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that
$$\dfrac d{dx}\left(\dfrac{x}{\ln x}\right)=\dfrac{\ln x-1}{(\ln x)^2}$$
Therefore, this function takes minimum value at $e$. Hence,
$$\dfrac{3}{\ln3}>\dfrac{e}{1}\\
\implies\boxed{\dfrac 3e>\ln3}$$

Answer (score 9):

Define $f(x)= {x \over e}-ln(x)$. Note that $$f'(x)= {1\over e}-{1\over x}$$

So $f'(x)\gt 0 $ for $x \gt e$. Thus $f(x)$ is increasing for $x \gt e$

Now, note that $f(e)=0$ and $3\gt e$.

Thus $f(3) \gt 0$    as  $f(e)=0$ and $f(3) \gt f(e)$

So $f(3)= {3 \over e}-ln(3) \gt 0$

Thus $$ {3 \over e}\gt ln(3) $$

Comment: Infact you can use this to show $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \gt 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume $f(x)=\frac{x}{e}$ and $g(x)=\ln(x)$.

$f(x)=g(x)$ for $x=e$ and $f$ grows faster than $g$. So I would say

$\frac{3}{e}>\ln(3)$, since $3>e$.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Compare the logs and use that $\ln $  is concave, hence its representative curve is below each of its tangents.